# Android ( java ) split String which Contains Special Characters?

Tags: java, android, string, soap, split

I am making an app that gets data from SOAP. When it has the data it must put it in a listview.
the result string is:

`it_id=636207115 :#=1:price=1,18|it_id=636207115 :#=1:price=1,18|it_id=636205395 :#=1:price=0,92`

I now have to split the string like this: `it_id=636207115 :#=1:price=1,18` , as you can see the `string splits at the '| '.`

But now i have to split the string again to get three strings from that. But i cant figure out how to split it then. I need to split that string at the ':' and put it then in the listview.

If anyone knows how to split split the string please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Encode your String` and then use `spilt()`   and than `Decode String` to Original

```
 try {
     str = URLEncoder.encode("t_id=636207115 :#=1:price=1,18|it_id=636207115 :#=1:price=1,18|it_id=636205395 :#=1:price=0,92", "UTF-8");
    } 
 catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

String abc[] = str.split("%7C"); // %7C is Encoded | by which you want to spilt the String

// Loop Through the Array and Decode the String !


for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    try {
         abc[i] = URLDecoder.decode(abc[i], "UTF-8");// Decoding String and Stroring it back to Array
         System.out.println(abc[i]);// Testing String 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

String selectedFromList = text.getText().toString();
                        String abc[] = selectedFromList.split(","); // %7C is Encoded | by which you want to spilt the String

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            if(i==abc.length-1)
                            Log.i("deepika deepika ::", abc[i]);
                            tvCountryName.setText(abc[i]);
                            edit.putString(COUNTRY, abc[i]);
                            edit.commit();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    String selectedFromList = "hello, hi, how are you, guys";
                    String abc[] = selectedFromList.split(",");
                    for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
                        try {

                            Log.i("deepika deepika ::", abc[i]);


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```